# Is there a book that presents the surahs of the Quran in chronological order with full description

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, history, islamic-basis, quranic-events

Not being fluent in Arabic, I have to rely on English translations and latin transliterations for trying to understand and pronounce the Quran.  I think alot of mine and other people's questions about the suras could be better understood if we knew the full story of each of the ayas of the suras as they were revealed to our Prophet (pbuh).

While I understand that the Quran is in the correct order as far as how the ayas and suras are laid out, this order is not chronological.  I looked in the local masjids for a text that describes the full biography of our prophet with the full story behind each of verses as they were revealed; ie the answers to companion's questions, lessons, sermons, trials, etc.  I could not find one.

Can anyone recommend such a text if it does exist?  Shukran

Comment: I don't know of any works that put verses in the order in which they were revealed, indeed the sequence is sometimes disputed for certain verses. However most tasfsirs will mention the background of the revealed verses where it has been recorded.

Comment: A somewhat related post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28856/is-it-possible-to-compile-the-quran-chronologically-are-there-books-about-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quran was the response to Prophet life and the situations. Situations were not in any order, they were not controlled and they were complex. In this sense, Quran is complex and whether it is arranged chronologically or as it is arranged by Prophet Mohammad (sallahu alaihi wassalam) with the help of angel Jibreel, will remain complex text.

Current arrangement has spiritual significance. It was in the order the way Allah (sw) wanted it to be. It was arranged by prophet sallahu alaihi wassalam himself by help of angel Jibreel.

Quran should be read interactively, that is, you read and you ponder. When you read about God punishment, you seek His mercy and when you read about His mercy, you feel happy to be part of it. When you read advice from Allah (sw), you become eager to do it and when you read about paradise, you seek it in your heart and when you read about hell, you ask for protection from it.

There is one surrah that was revelead in chronological order, and that is surah Yusuf.

Comment: Brother, you seem to misunderstood the meaning of chronological order. It means...   
"The definition of chronological is arranged in the order it happened. An example of chronological is a biography that starts in 1920 and goes through 1997